# Magento 2 - Customize Customer Grid Collection Data

Tags: magento2, admin, collection, customer-grid

I want to add a where clause in customer grid collection. 
e.g.

```
$currentCollection->getSelect()->where('custom condition');
```

I tried to google it but got no success.
I have also tried to implement customization methods used for product and order grid but it seems that di.xml and ui component xml files are different.

e.g when I try to add code

```
<argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFieldToCollection</item>
</argument>
```

in file **/app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

I get

```
Element 'arguments': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ).
```

I have also tried modifying collection through observer but it seems event `customer_grid_collection_load_before` does not exist.

I don't want to modify core code and I have no clue from where to start. Please comment if any other information needed.

Comment: do you want this condition for every loaded customer, or you want to filter loaded collection after displaying a grid (for not every customer)?

Comment: I want to add filter to collection before grid is loaded. e.g. customer collection is loaded in variable $customerCollection then I want to add a where condition like $customerCollection->where('Custom condition goes here');

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
I was wrong - in Magento 2 grid is built other way, look at this:
http://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/

And here you can find way to add custom filter for grid collection
[To add default filter to grid in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2)

Comment: This is the issue in which I am stuck. I am unable to find which block file is used or contains prepareCollection function. The module-customer uses /etc/di.xml and /view/ui_component/customer_listing.xml for displaying customer grid in admin section.