# Magento 2 : How can I load an admin grid with pre-defined filter values?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, filter

I want to create a link to a custom grid in my admin with pre-defined filters. The grid is made with a UI Listing Component (XML) and it has a column called `form_id` that is setup like this:

```
<column name="form_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Form id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

The grid works just fine. I can apply the filter and everything works well. The grid gets nicely updated with a XHR request.

However... I want to be able to have a filters' value pre-defined at some point. For example, I want to be able to open the grid when it's filtered on ID=3.

So I already tried loading the page with the same URL parameters as the XHR-request, as well as simply adding the only required parameters:

```
?namespace=form_response_listing&search=&filters[placeholder]=true&filters[form_id][from]=3&filters[form_id][to]=3&paging[pageSize]=20&paging[current]=1
```

As well as:

```
?filters[form_id][from]=3&filters[form_id][to]=3
```

Both with no success. So how Can I pre-fill filters by using the URL?

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of the other question (as mentioned in the comments below). In my case, I'm using a virtual type as collection for my grid:

```
<virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Response\Grid\Collection"
             type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendormodule_form_response</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Response</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

So it's not that I have a physical Block class for my grid widget, it's purely created with a UI Component listing XML.

Nevertheless, I'll check anyway if the question referred to will help my use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To add default filter to grid in Magento2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I don't think this is a duplicate. The question you linked talks about grids build in an old fashion way. Something between grid blocks and ui-components. It was basically something where you still had grid blocks but they were configured in an xml file instead of `prepareColumns` method.

Comment: @Marius vote retracted ;)

Comment: I edited my question, since I also don't think this is a duplicate (I've done my research ;-))

Comment: @Giel Berkers 
I am getting same issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what I found out so far.
This is not complete but it can take you on the right path.
I conducted my tests by modifying the cms page listing ui component.
I added this

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="page_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
</item>
```

in `cms_page_listing.xml` inside the dataSource node inside the data/config argument. So now it looks like this

```
<dataSource name="cms_page_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">cms_page_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">page_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">page_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array"><!-- my addition -->
                    <item name="page_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

This allows me to call the url `ROOT/admin/cms/page/index/key/<form_key_here>/?page_id=2`.
And I see only the page with id 2.
But it does not work for range filters and the filter value is not filled in. It still shows as blank.

Now here is why this is possible.

The dataProvider class for cms pages is `Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\DataProvider`.
This one extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider`.
This last one contains a protected method called `prepareUpdateUrl`

```
protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
{
    if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
        if ('*' == $paramValue) {
            $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
        }
        if ($paramValue) {
            $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                '%s%s/%s',
                $this->data['config']['update_url'],
                $paramName,
                $paramValue
            );
            $this->addFilter(
                $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is to check in the ui component config if there is an element called `filter_url_params`. If there is, it takes all the values inside it and checks the request for values matching what's defined in `filter_url_params`.
But by default it works only with `eq`.

What you can try is to have a custom dataSource for your component where you rewrite the method `prepareUpdateUrl` and make it take into account all the request variables you need and maybe add paging to it and range filtering.

Side note: This is a very interesting question. I'm sure a lot of people will need this in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Marius for your answer. This works for my situation, because the link always needs to filter by one ID, not by a range (the range is more or less a feature, but not required by my URL). Your answer as well as your explanation helped me a lot!

Comment: @Marius can i use the url like this `ROOT/admin/cms/page/index/page_id/2/key/<form_key_here>`, because i'm using `$this->urlBuilder->getUrl(static::URL_PATH,[ 'page_id' => $item['id']])` in UiCompnent/Listing/Column

Comment: how do I use more than one param to filter, i.e. ROOT/admin/cms/page/index/param_1/val1/param_2/val2/param_3/val3/key/<form_key_here>

giving three params under <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array"> works for individual filters but not collectively.

Comment: @Marius ! U R A LIFE SAVER !

Comment: @Marius : Do you have idea, how to use the functionality for multiple url param like ROOT/admin/cms/page/index/param_1/val1/param_2/val2/param_3/‌​val3/key/<form_key_h‌​ere>
as already specified by Shathish

Comment: Try adding multiple nodes under the filter_url_params

Comment: @Marius : Thanks for reply, we have already tried to add two nodes like <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="event_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                    </item> 
and in url ".../event_id/6/status/1/"
but this filter_url_params is picking only first node "event_id" for filter
Please help, how to use multiple.

Comment: @Marius: I have done it some how by adding <item name="status" xsi:type="string">1</item> the static value 1 is working but * is not working for 2nd node of filter_url_params.
Thanks for the post.

Comment: i don't have any other ideas

Comment: @AshishRaj Hi, if you have multiple options to filter, you could try a way here [Add default custom_attribute filter to product grid in Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203190/add-default-custom-attribute-filter-to-product-grid-in-magento-2-1), it worked for me :)

Comment: I used the above code and add the custom parameter, but while i get the current page url, the newly added parameters are not there.
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

Comment: I want to apply the default filter on grid load. And also able to reset filter on grid. I use your code but every time it is load default filter. I have boolean field.

Comment: I add `filter_url_params` item tag in `dataSource` tag.