# filter_condition_callback using Ui Component - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, renderer

I have a customer column in my custom module admin grid (created using UI component) where I show the customer name. But in database I save customer Id. I need to use the filter on customer name as input box in my grid filters. When I filter the grid by customer ID it works fine.

My question is how I can filter it by using customer name?
Same as we do in Magento 1 using filter_condition_callback.

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155309/magento-2-how-can-i-load-an-admin-grid-with-pre-defined-filter-values/155316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by joining my custom module collection with 'customer_grid_flat' table.

In Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModuleName\Collection.php

```
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('customer_grid_flat');
    $this->getSelect()->joinleft($joinTable.' as customer','main_table.customer_id = customer.entity_id', array('name'=> 'name'));
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

And in Uicomponent xml Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/custom_module_listing.xml added column for field 'name'

```
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you already have `name` column in the main table (or, for example, join yet another table that has `name` column).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If one wants to join eav_attribute_option_value table to filtering option value, one can use below code.

```
$this->addColumn(
        'product_manufacturer',
        [
            'header' => __('Manufacturer'),
            'index' => 'manufacturer',
            'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, 'filterCustomManufacturer'],
            'header_css_class' => 'col-manufacturer',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-manufacturer'
        ]
    );
```

Below add filter condition callback function including joins like,

```
protected function filterCustomManufacturer($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('c_p_e_i'=>'catalog_product_entity_int'),
    'e.row_id = c_p_e_i.row_id',array('value'));

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('attribute_option'=>'eav_attribute_option_value'),
    'c_p_e_i.value = attribute_option.option_id and attribute_option.store_id = 0',
     array('eaov_val'=>'value' , 'eaov_option'=>'option_id'));

     $collection->getSelect()->where("`attribute_option`.`value` like ?", "%$value%");

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check

[Magento 2 : How can I load an admin grid with pre-defined filter values?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155309/magento-2-how-can-i-load-an-admin-grid-with-pre-defined-filter-values/155316)

U have to apply

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="customer_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
</item>
```

& follow for code. Check in URL it's passing or not.

https://github.com/thejinxters/magento2-testing/blob/master/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/DataProvider.php

U need to add `prepareUpdateUrl()` function

Comment: I am using UI component for this. So where I need to define the _addColumnFilterToCollection ?

Comment: It's a different function. U can define after/before `_prepareCollection()`. Can print query for log

Comment: I didn't used file CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Edit\Tab\Grid.php for fetching collection. Rather I have used CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid\Collection.php which extends ...\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection.php and fetching the collection from there. Could you tell me the path where should I write those functions?

Comment: U r using .xml file  for listing?

Comment: Yes as mentioned in question I am using ui-component in .xml.

Comment: Please check now updated answer

Comment: This will work for setting default filter. I have tried above solution but each time I am getting the value set for <item> in xml. In above case each time I am getting * in prepareUpdateUrl() function.

Comment: How to reset default filter?