# Passing request variable to Products Grid AJAX URL (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, product-grid, listing-component

When you enter `/admin/catalog/product/` - products grid is fetched from `/admin/mui/index/render/?namespace=product_listing&filters[placeholder]=true&filters[store_id]=1&paging[pageSize]=20&paging[current]=1&sorting[field]=entity_id&sorting[direction]=asc&isAjax=true` (this URL is generated by JS).

Need method to pass the request variable to the URL responsible for loading products grid. I mean that entering: `/admin/catalog/product/whatever/123/` will fetch data grid from URL `/admin/mui/index/render/?namespace=product_listing&filters[placeholder]=true&filters[store_id]=1&paging[pageSize]=20&paging[current]=1&sorting[field]=entity_id&sorting[direction]=asc&whatever=123&isAjax=true`

I tried to change XML config for:

`<item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
<item name="exports" xsi:type="array">`

But it doesn't affect the URL structure. Do you have any clear ideas for resolving the problem?

Comment: Did you get solution for this case?

Comment: I didn't solved this in _magento way_ however I've added JS file that is copy of module responsible for search - this fetches URL and passes variable to "chips" - that Magento by default uses for building URL. (view/base/web/js/grid/vendor/variable.js). If I find any better solution - I'll submit it as resolution.

Comment: I got a solution here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155316/34070

Comment: Already knew this solution - and (at least on 2.1.2) it didn't work as expected.