# Add default custom_attribute filter to product grid in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, filter, uicomponent, listing

I add a custom **select attribute** in product, I can show it in the grid listing of custom module. But how to make a **default custom_attribute filter**? You could look the example image below, which I want filter the collection to show Image Request with requesting.

[image: Add default custom_attribute filter to product grid in Magento 2.1]

You could try solution in  Magento 2.1 `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml`. Had better use ui_component way.

I had tried some ways in our site, all doesn't work, below are the solutions which **doesn't work** in Magento2.1.

[To add default filter to grid in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2)

[Magento 2 : How can I load an admin grid with pre-defined filter values?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155309/magento-2-how-can-i-load-an-admin-grid-with-pre-defined-filter-values?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying many codes which doesn't work, finally find **a way doesn't need coding** - make use of **saving custom views** function which **could save filter and column settings**.

### Specific steps

**After** setting filter and column settings, click on the <kbd>Default View</kbd> button with the eye icon, then click <kbd>Save View As…</kbd> to enter a name for your view. Then you could click the custom view whenever you want to get the grid just the way you like it, and you can save custom views as many as you like.

You can also go back and use the edit icon to rename it or delete it later on, or to return to the default view.

I think this is a very good function in Magento 2 :)

[image]