# Default filtering in UI Component Grid

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, grid, filter, uicomponent

I need to filter a grid view to show only where is_approved = true on one of my grids.

This needs to happen on page load (i.e. don't want the user to have to specify a filter).

The grids are made through UI Components, not blocks [so this answer and similar applicable](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2?answertab=active#tab-top). I also [find the docs a bit vague/not complete](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-filter.html) (what does "..." mean?!)

I'm not quite sure where to start after having tried various options but can't find any documentation on it or answered questions.

**UI Component**

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sample_post_listing.sample_post_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sample_post_listing.sample_post_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">sample_post_listing.sample_post_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterInput name="is_approved">0</filterInput>
        </filters>
```

...

```
    <column name="is_approved">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pending</item>
                </item>
                <item name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Approved</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

**Data Injection**

```
<!-- Data Providers for Admin Grids -->
<virtualType name="PostsGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Sample\Sample\Model\Resource\Subscription\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">SubscriptionGirdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<!-- Grid Collections -->
<virtualType name="Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sample_sample_posts</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts</argument>
        <argument name="default_filter" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="id" xsi:type="string">0</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can create your own collection which will provide the items you like.

Create a new collection. *Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid\Collection*

that collection should:

- a. Implement the *Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface*.
  Check the functions of that Interface and put them in your collection
- b. Better extend your already existing Collection:
  Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Collection

So the new collection should be like that:

```
<?php
namespace Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts;

class Collection extends \Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Collection implements 
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{

    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory            
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger            
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy            
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager            
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager            
     * @param mixed|null $mainTable            
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix            
     * @param mixed $eventObject            
     * @param mixed $resourceModel            
     * @param string $model            
     * @param null $connection            
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     *            @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     *            
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory, 
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy, 
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager, 
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, $mainTable, $eventPrefix, $eventObject, $resourceModel, 
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document', $connection = null, \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface $aggregations            
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return $this->searchCriteria;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria            
     * @return $this @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        $this->searchCriteria = $searchCriteria;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount            
     * @return $this @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items            
     * @return $this @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * This is the function that will add the filter
     */
    protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        parent::_beforeLoad();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('is_approved',['eq'=>true]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

- Check the last function named _beforeLoad()
  This adds the filter you like

then go the di.xml and replace:

```
<virtualType name="Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sample_sample_posts</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts</argument>
        <argument name="default_filter" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="id" xsi:type="string">0</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

with:

```
<type name="Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sample_sample_posts</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Sample\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Posts</argument>            
    </arguments>
</type>
```

You can now have full control of the collection.
You can find a similar example here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Collection.php

Comment: Here, where can we have to register our data source ??

Answer (score 11):

## Vanilla out of the box can achieve default filter

Inject below configs to your listing component, e.g., `your_ui_component.xml`

```xml
<listing ...>
    <listingToolbar ...>
        <filters ...>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="applied" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_approved" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Flush bookmark cache

```sql
delete from ui_bookmark;
```

You will also need to flush Magento cache as you have modified di.xml or your_ui_component.xml

```bash
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**NOTE:** injection can be done in different froms. For example, it can also be done with setting `<filters class="YourVirtualType" />` and in `di.xml` inject the `data.config.applied` array to `<virtualType name="YourVirtualType" />` to achieve sharing.

## How does it work

Ui component is just a js class and data is injected from your setup or from **bookmark** (i.e., a data storage)

```sql
mysql> select * from ui_bookmark order by bookmark_id desc limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
bookmark_id: 39
    user_id: 1
  namespace: product_listing
 identifier: current
    current: 0
      title: NULL
     config: {"current":{"columns":{"entity_id":{"visible":true,"sorting":"asc"},"name":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"sku":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"price":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"websites":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"qty":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"short_description":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"special_price":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"cost":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"weight":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"meta_title":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"meta_keyword":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"meta_description":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"url_key":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"msrp":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"ids":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"type_id":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"attribute_set_id":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"visibility":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"status":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"manufacturer":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"color":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"custom_design":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"page_layout":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"country_of_manufacture":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"custom_layout":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"tax_class_id":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"gift_message_available":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"actions":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"thumbnail":{"visible":true,"sorting":false},"special_from_date":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"special_to_date":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"news_from_date":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"news_to_date":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"custom_design_from":{"visible":false,"sorting":false},"custom_design_to":{"visible":false,"sorting":false}},"displayMode":"grid","paging":{"options":{"20":{"value":20,"label":20},"30":{"value":30,"label":30},"50":{"value":50,"label":50},"100":{"value":100,"label":100},"200":{"value":200,"label":200}},"value":20},"positions":{"ids":0,"entity_id":1,"thumbnail":2,"name":3,"type_id":4,"attribute_set_id":5,"sku":6,"price":7,"qty":8,"visibility":9,"status":10,"websites":11,"short_description":12,"special_price":13,"special_from_date":14,"special_to_date":15,"cost":16,"weight":17,"manufacturer":18,"meta_title":19,"meta_keyword":20,"meta_description":21,"color":22,"news_from_date":23,"news_to_date":24,"custom_design":25,"custom_design_from":26,"custom_design_to":27,"page_layout":28,"country_of_manufacture":29,"custom_layout":30,"url_key":31,"msrp":32,"tax_class_id":33,"gift_message_available":34,"actions":35},"filters":{"applied":{"placeholder":true,"status":"2"}}}}
 created_at: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
 updated_at: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When you interact with the grid (e.g., moving columns order, filtering, etc...), Magento persists it into ui_bookmark with the same data structure you can inject.

If you look into `config`, you will find the `filters` data which offers a way to inject default filter.

```json
{
  "current": {
    ...
    "filters": {
      "applied": {
        "placeholder": true,
        "status": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More details on what config you can inject, see 
[vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/filters.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/filters.js#L51-L53)

[image: Catalog grid filtering with disabled products]

The above is an example of catalog product grid filtering with disabled products