# Magento 2 adminhtml custom column sorting ascending and descending

Tags: magento2, admin, sorting, column

I made a custom column in `sales_order_invoice_grid` to display some additional data. This works fine but when clicking on the given column it does not react on any sorting mechanism like descending and ascending

Here is what I got

`sales_order_invoice_grid`

```
 <column name="order_state" class="Foobar\InvoiceOrderStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

The corresponding class

```
class Status extends Column
{

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {

                $orderId = $item["order_id"];
                if (empty($orderId)) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = "unkown";
                    continue;
                }

                /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepo */
                $orderRepo = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository');
                /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
                $order = $orderRepo->get($orderId);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $order->getStatus();
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }


}
```

How can I apply descending / ascending sorting to my custom column?

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2/97472#97472) and I hope this will help you out.

Comment: In my case I modified the ui_component/sales_order_invoice_grid.xml is there something similar?

Answer (score 4):

```
<column name="order_state" class="Foobar\InvoiceOrderStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Status</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

You just need to add asc or desc sorting tab

```
<item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
```