# magento 2 apply a custom filter in the grid

Tags: magento2, grid, filter

[image]I have a grid and I want to apply a custom filter on it, is there a way do that ?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide more information. Did you use UI Component?

Comment: Please check below URL
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2

Comment: @SalmaSaiyad yes, i used ui component I have the filters of the default columns I want to add a custom filter, I added a photo that indicates the filter location to the question

Comment: @lisa You can take a reference from following answer

Answer (score 2):

You can take the reference for Status filter added in following XML to add custom filters. More information you can find here. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-filters.html

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters_modifier" xsi:type="array"/>
                    </item>
                    <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Filters</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <statefull>
                    <property name="applied" xsi:type="boolean">false</property>
                </statefull>
            </settings>
        <filterSelect name="status" provider="${ $.parentName }">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status"/>
                <caption translate="true">Select...</caption>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
                <dataScope>status</dataScope>
                <imports>
                    <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
```

Comment: Do you know how can we apply filter logic to query? I mean in which file we can add if you find custom filter (here status) then apply the filter logic.

Comment: @Knight017, were you able to find how can we apply filter logic

Comment: @surbhiagr not remeber exactly, but we have to find out the file which is used for collection filter from core,may be in di.xml where they specify the class , then need to rewrite it or we update it in di.xml and add the logic there.