# How to use addFieldToFilter on ui grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, uicomponent, ui-grid

[image]

From them image above you can see the first record does not have name.

I want all the record which have name should be displayed and which doesn't have should not be listed in grid.

I know how to use addFieldToFilter in php file but don't know how to use in UI Grid.

```
        $collection =$this->MainOr->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter("parent_id", array("neq" => 0));
```

Comment: try this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2

Comment: Ya but i am using UI component for listing

Comment: @avesh There is always a collection class linked with the ui grid, kindly check your module's di.xml , it should be there. Paste it here as well.

Comment: Can you write the ans?

Comment: @AnshuMishra Element 'updater': This element is not expected. Line 9 ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add filter in collection.php with

```
 protected function _initSelect()
{
parent::_initSelect();
$this>addFieldToFilter("parent_id", array("neq" => 0));
return $this;
}
```

and extend collection.php in  your grid/collection.php file

Try and Let me know if you want more help!!!

Comment: Ma'am it's not working i inserted code in collection.php file

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: You have to set your filter over here i have just give you a way that you can set filter over here $this>addFieldToFilter("parent_id", array("neq" => 0));   @avesh

Comment: Ya i inserted the code in collection.php, model/ResourceModel/ModelName/Collection.php

Comment: Have you extend this collection in grid/collection? @avesh

Comment: Yes using the Di.xml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82182/discussion-between-rutvee-sojitra-and-avesh).

Comment: you said that the di.xml should not change, well it should have been changed

Comment: you said that the di.xml should not change, well it should have been changed

Comment: After all your ans was right. Thank you for the help

Comment: it's working for me .....
is it possible to create two collections in same Resource model

Comment: How to apply default filter on ui grid?

Answer (score 2):

To add value to grid in ui component. 
Sample here. 
First you should see in view/adminhtml/ui_component/xxxx_listing.xml

```
 <dataSource name="xxxx_grid_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">CompanyName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\XXXXX\VendorDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" path="mui/index/render" xsi:type="url"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

That defind dataProvider CompanyName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\XXXXX\VendorDataProvider

and class dataProvider will be like this.

```
<?php
   namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Xxxxx;

   use Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository;
     use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting;
     use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
    use CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\XXXXX\CollectionFactory;


   class VendorDataProvider extends 


  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
   {
/**
 * @var AttributeRepository
 */
private $attributeRepository;

/**
 * @param string                $name
 * @param string                $primaryFieldName
 * @param string                $requestFieldName
 * @param Reporting             $reporting
 * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 * @param RequestInterface      $request
 * @param FilterBuilder         $filterBuilder
 * @param AttributeRepository   $attributeRepository
 * @param array                 $meta
 * @param array                 $data
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    Reporting $reporting,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    RequestInterface $request,
    FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;

    parent::__construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        $reporting,
        $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        $request,
        $filterBuilder,
        $meta,
        $data
    );
}

/**
 * @param SearchResultInterface $searchResult
 * @return array
 */
protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
{
    $arrItems = [];
    $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();

    $arrItems['items'] = [];
    foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
        $arrItems['items'][] = $item->getData();
    }

    return $arrItems;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getData()
{
    $collection = $this->getSearchResult();
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect([
            'logo',
            'email',
            'shop_name',
            'status'
        ]);

    $data = $this->searchResultToOutput($collection);

    return $data;
}}
```

you can rewrite function getData to addAttributeToSelect for collection.
Then it will show result to grid. If it work please vote for me. :)

Comment: It worked, but I had to remove the argument  `<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">...` that is inside the data source because I was having a js issue, i move it outside and add the item provider and deps `<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xxx_listing.vendor_grid_data_source</item>` and `<item name="deps" xsi:type="string">xxx_listing.vendor_grid_data_source</item>` instead of `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>`

Answer (score 1):

in your listing.xml file above the line

```
<item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
```

add the id you are passing in the url like in my case

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="page_id" xsi:type="boolean">1</item>
                    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rutvee Sojitra, I applied the changes but nothing reflects, also extended the collection.php in the grid collection. Can you help me..

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Issue resolved thanks applied some different solution.