# how to add default filter in magento admin ui component in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, xml, uicomponent

> Hi I want to filter the admin grid data in default Magento 2
>
> how to add default filter in Magento admin **UI component in Magento 2**

[image]

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97472/49826

Comment: could you plzz explain that answer

Comment: This answer was helpful to solve the problem... https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/239498/73525