# Magento 2 Filter admin grid collection by default

Tags: filter, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I want to filter the custom grid using custom attribute. I followed [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2?noredirect=1). But it is not working. Is any alternate solution there.

Comment: Add your whole code.